# Models for vibrations and stress waves generated due to impact?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, vibrations

Say that a small metal ball impacts a long thin cylindrical rod from above (let's say height of around 10 cm) in an elastic collision and causes stress waves to propagate left and right from the point of collision. Is there some model in literature that describes the shape of stress wave (spatially) that will be generated? I am assuming a sinusoidal stress wave won't be created and that the wave would be described by some sort of random power spectral density. Is that correct?

I am also curious about the time dynamics of the stress wave - is it correct to say that higher frequencies decay faster than lower frequency ones?

I'm from an EE background (hence not much background in mechanics) working on a research problem, and would greatly appreciate any tips that would help me get started!

Comment: This kind of question is usually approached experimentally and that data is then integrated into design tools with finite element solvers etc.. The theoretical answers are, IMHO, simply not reliable for real world work. I once saw an aerospace engineer do design studies very similar to your case. The source was the explosive bolt detonator on a spacecraft release mechanism and he was using actually recorded acceleration data (i.e. "sound") from a test on the actual launch vehicle hardware to simulate the impact on the payload.

Comment: Sure, I plan to use finite element solvers and validate experimentally as well, but I am trying to build a theoretical framework that gives a high-level description of what happens (it doesn't have to be 100% accurate). Could you please point me toward any reference papers or give any keywords that I could search? I assumed stress wave generation is a fairly well studied problem in mechanical/aerospace engineering, and just wanted to know the names of the underlying theorems/laws/models so I can do more self-study :)

Comment: Also, when reading some course lectures, I came to understand structures will support vibration modes, but I don't really understand if a sudden impact will excite any of those modes - maybe only a specific type of perturbation by a transducer will couple to vibration modes. It would be great to get clarification on this point.

Comment: To be frank, physicists are not particularly interested in structural mechanics. You are basically bringing an engineering question to a science site. The basics that you will need to solve this problem are a solid understanding of continuum mechanics and numerical finite element techniques on the mechanical engineering level, which is very different from the physics level. The most an average physicist knows about mechanical engineering is the loaded horizontal beam... we do analyses of resonances and wave phenomena in solids, but not much of the kind that you are talking about.

Comment: Which modes get excited depends on the spectrum of the impact it's location and the details of the forces at the impact point. Like I said, if you study continuum mechanics then you will get all the tools to do these kinds of analyses, but that's, at least, a couple of semesters of coursework before you really know what you are doing, it's not something that we can explain here on a page.